# DataStax Graph Fuzz Query

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, titan, gremlin

I am actually experimenting with DSE (Datastax Entreprise) Graph and i am stuck in a problem: i would like to do a gremlin fuzzy query on DSE. Basicaly, it will return the strings that has the highest match scores. I know you can do that in TitanDb by using the graph.indexQuery command.
Is there any equivalent to this gremlin command in DSE?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the indexing overview of DSE Graph.  https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/indexOverview.html?hl=index

We enable this functionality through the integration with DSE Search (i.e. DataStax's integration with SOLR).  Right now we are tied to String and Text searching, but in the near future we'll be able to leverage DSE Search fully through Gremlin.

Comment: Thank for your help. Do you know exactly when the gremlin functionality will be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

We are looking to expose the first phase of this functionality in 5.0.4, our next release.  This is targeted to be released this month.